# How do spammers add icons to their mail subjects?

Tags: gmail, outlook.com, emoji

Looking at the junk mail folder of my outlook.com account, I see some mails that have unusual icons on them - check box, American flag, maple leaf (symbolizing Canada I suppose, though the color is a bit off).

At first I thought these where some wacky new emojis. But looking at `Inspect element`, those appear as img tags - for example, the US flag is `<img src="https://a.gfx.ms/emoji_1F1FA_1F1F8.png" class="Emoji$1F1FA_1F1F8$C76 RenderedEmoji" title="מחוון אזורי עבור ארה" ב"="" alt="מחוון אזורי עבור ארה">`.

How do spammers get Outlook.com to render these icons?

[image: Outlook.com with icons]

[image]

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095387/animated-icon-in-email-subject

Comment: That's the answer I've been looking for - non-standard emoji's rendered by outlook.com - and apparently gmail as well, wonder if they're standard between them and other providers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In view of OP's Comment (*That's the answer I've been looking for* ...) to [@Mr White](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/5434/mrwhite)'s Comment:

> See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095387/animated-icon-in-email-subject

A few lines from [@Alexander O'Mara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3155639/alexander-omara)'s comprehensive answer:

> They are referred to internally as goomoji, and they appear to be a non-standard UTF-8 extension. When Gmail encounters one of these characters, it is replaced by the corresponding icon. I wasn't able to find any documentation on them, but I was able to reverse engineer the format.